# GetWindowText hangs on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10, freeze

**TL;DR: Did GetWindowText win32 api change behavior on windows 10?**

I have some code that loops through all windows on the desktop to find a window where the title contains some text.

When this code hits a window named "" with class "URL Moniker Notification Window" it hangs on GetWindowText.

GetWindowText is trying to send a message, my guess is WM_GETTEXT.

This window is part of the exe "SearchUI.exe", the process is suspended and can't process messages.

When reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833/
according to rule 2, this should not happen.

This code has been working fine for years. (win 7, 8, 8.1)

**So did GetWindowText change behavior in Windows 10?**

Update:
The code in question.

```
public static int HwndGet(string partialTitle, string klassenavn)
{
  partialTitle = partialTitle ?? "";
  var cTitleTemp = new StringBuilder(255);
  var hWndTemp = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, null, null);
  var nypartialTitle = partialTitle.ToUpper();
  while (hWndTemp != (IntPtr)0)
  {
    GetWindowText(hWndTemp, cTitleTemp, cTitleTemp.Capacity);
    string sTitleTemp = cTitleTemp.ToString();
    sTitleTemp = sTitleTemp.ToUpper();

    if (sTitleTemp.StartsWith(nypartialTitle, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
      var className = new StringBuilder(255);
      GetClassName(hWndTemp, className, 255);
      //sTitleTemp: " + sTitleTemp + " ClassName: " + ClassName);

      if (className.ToString().StartsWith(klassenavn, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        return (int)hWndTemp;
      }
    }

    hWndTemp = GetWindow(hWndTemp, GwHwndnext);
  }
  return 0; // does not find the window
}
```

Stack trace:

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Seems more likely that there is a defect in your code

Comment: The FindWindowEx, the GetWindowText, the GetClassName and the GetWindow (and other pinvoke functions, if I've missed them)... You should post your definitions

Comment: You neglect to check for errors in this code. A sad state of affairs that we see time after time after time.

Comment: And there is an error in and *sTitleTemp: " + sTitleTemp + " ClassName: " + ClassName);*

Comment: And finally the problem is probably that `FindWindowsEx` + `GetWindow(GwHwndnext)` isn't a safe way for enumerating windows: the windows could change during the calls. To enumerate all the windows you should use `EnumWindows`

Comment: "The process is suspended".  Look no further.  And sure, you never encountered the UWP apps before so that is new.

Comment: @xanatos you are correct there is an error, it is half a comment I forgot to clean up

Comment: The problem is not how I enumerate the Windows, but that a call to GetWindowText never returns.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are using isn't "safe". There is no guarantee that the order of the windows won't change between calls to `FindWindowsEx` and `GetWindow(GwHwndnext)`. For this reason there is another API, `EnumWindows`, that is "safe". You could try with it.

Here there is a sample program (based on the one found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows)).

```
public static class WndSearcher
{
    public static IntPtr SearchForWindow(string wndclass, string title)
    {
        var sd = new SearchData { Wndclass = wndclass, Title = title };

        EnumWindows(sd.EnumWindowsProc, IntPtr.Zero);
        return sd.hWndFound;
    }

    private class SearchData
    {
        // You can put any dicks or Doms in here...
        public string Wndclass;
        public string Title;

        public IntPtr hWndFound;

        public bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // Check classname and title 
            var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            int res = GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

            if (res == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }

            if (sb.ToString().StartsWith(Wndclass, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                sb.Clear();

                res = GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

                if (res == 0)
                {
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                    if (error != 0) 
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(error);
                    }
                }

                if (sb.ToString().StartsWith(Title, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    hWndFound = hWnd;
                    // Found the wnd, halt enumeration
                    return false;    
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
}
```

and then use it like

```
IntPtr ptr = WndSearcher.SearchForWindow("classname", "windowname");
```

Comment: Nice code, my solution is also to call GetClassName first, so I will never hit the suspended process. But it is not an answer to my question.

Comment: GetWindowText can return 0 if there is no title of a window, so this code will always throw an exception.
Replace **if (res == 0)** after GetWindowText with
          **var errorNum = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
          if (res == 0 && errorNum != 0)**

Comment: @NickolaiNielsen Right... I've done it in a little different way.